# TSQL: Special (National) char detection (SQL Server2016)

Tags: t-sql

I found a lot of techniques to detect aka special chars($%@#) avail on English keyboard, however I see that some national char like  á  works differently, though my LIKE condition should get it, as it should select  anything but a-z1-9, what is the trick here: In sample below I'm missing my special á. I'm on TSQL 2016 with default settings in US.

```
    ;WITH cte AS (SELECT 'Euro a€'  St UNION  SELECT 'adgkjb$' St UNION SELECT 'Bravo Endá' St)
    SELECT * FROM cte WHERE St LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%'

        St
        adgkjb$
        Euro a€
   SELECT CAST(N'€' AS VARBINARY(8))    --0xAC20
   SELECT CAST(N'á' AS VARBINARY(8))    --0xE100
```

Comment: Please note that caret in square brackets should indicate NOT for the whole set.

Comment: are you wanting to drop it or convert it to a standard a?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server appears to be *helping* with ranges of characters due to the default collation. If you explicitly list all of the valid characters it will work as desired. Alternatively, you can force a collation on the pattern match that won't interpret the pattern a containing non-ASCII characters.

```
-- Explicit pattern for "bad" characters.
declare @InvalidCharactersPattern as VarChar(100) = '%[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ]%';

-- Query some sample data with the explicit pattern and an explicitly specified collation.
select Sample,
  case when Sample like @InvalidCharactersPattern then 'Bad Character' else 'Okay' end as ExplicitStatus,
  case when Sample like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%' collate Latin1_General_100_BIN
    then 'Bad Character' else 'Okay' end as CollationStatus
  from ( values ( 'a' ), ( 'A' ), ( 'á' ), ( 'Foo' ), ( 'F&o' ), ( '$%^&' ) ) as Samples( Sample );

-- Server collation.
select ServerProperty( 'collation' ) as ServerCollation;

-- Available collations.
select name, description
  from sys.fn_helpcollations()
  order by name;
```

Comment: Tx HABO, so that one missed could be in range? let say in A thru Z? do they go by Hex values on background?

Comment: @MikeS The answer has been updated to include information about collations. There are likely many choices for collation that don't contain accented characters. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support) is a good starting point.